# Displaying the right content on a page url

Tags: theme-development

I created a WordPress theme with one page design format which means I wrote all the code in the main index.php file. Now I need to make a different page with separate URL but for some reason it still displays the same content.

Basically https://mypage.com is the main page and I need to have a new separate page for some content like https://mypage.com/something but for some reason whenever I create a new page it still shows the content from the main page.

I don't know what's the WordPress way of doing things like that, should I just create a new directory with new files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Because the naming convention is matter](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). You can create a new template for your different page and name it "**page.php**" and on the header portion give it a name:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template name: Different page tempate
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="yourclass">
    <!-- Your different template code should go here -->
</div>


<?php
get_footer();
```

Once you are done then go to Pages>Add New & on the right sidebar you will see the new template name under "Template" dropdown. Select it as your new page template and publish.
[image]

Comment: Ohh, thank you very much sir. It's exactly what i was looking for, i had no idea about different templates before.

Comment: You are most welcome!